# Insert into a table only those records which doesn't exists found by a join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Below is the query which finds the matching record and returns those `"main"."item"."id"` which matches the values inside IN clause.

```
select main.item_vendor.item_id
from main.item_vendor
join main.item on item.id = main.item_vendor.item_id
WHERE "main"."item"."id" IN ('188646', '200000699')
```

Above query returns only one value which has record for `188646` and for other it is missing. Now I need to use above query and INSERT values in `main.item_vendor` table just for this `200000699`.

How can I plugin below INSERT query into above join query so that it can insert only for those which doesn't exist. Meaning I want to insert in `main.item_vendor` table only for `200000699` item id since it doesn't exist.

```
INSERT INTO "main"."item_vendor" ("item_id", "vendor_id", audit_by, currency_id )
VALUES (200000699, ?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: If I understand correct, you want the item_vendor.id to be unique? Why not simply set a unique constraint?

Comment: I just want to insert record into `item_vendor` table which doesn't exist from my where clause `WHERE "main"."item"."id" IN ('188646', '200000699')`. Basically find those `"main"."item"."id"` which doesn't exist and then insert them in item_vendor table.

Comment: you can use INSERT INTO ... but instead of VALUES you can put SELECT ..., as long as columns and data-types match

Comment: @tinazmu Can you provide an example on how can I plug this into here?

Comment: you want to insert into item_vendor with 4 columns, but your select query returns 1 item, where would the values for audit_by, currency_id come from? you need to provide more info for a valid example,

Comment: For those columns I need to pass the values manually in which I need to insert into those columns. You can use any random value for now but I will be passing them and inserting those values in.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood! so you have these two item_ids: 1888646 and 200000699 and you want to check if these exist in item_vendor and insert if not? I guess you can have more than two at times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250447/discussion-between-rosed-and-tinazmu).

Comment: @tinazmu yes we can have more than two.. and also yes insert if it doesn't exist in item_vendor table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with wNotExists as (
  select main.item.id as notExistsId
    from main.item_vendor
    right join main.item on main.item.id = main.item_vendor.item_id
    where main.item_vendor.item_id is null
      and main.item.id IN ('188646', '200000699') -- comment this line for getting all "id" from "item" not exists in "item_vendor"
)
insert into main.item_vendor (item_id, vendor_id, audit_by, currency_id)
  select notExistsId, ?, ?, ?
    from wNotExists;
```

Comment: why right join here? can you please explain?

Comment: sure, right join to get all the date from 2nd table, if the 1st one doesn't match - all those rows will be iqual to NULL, so when you add "where 1st.id is null" you will get all from the 2nd table that doesn't exist in the 1st table.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use a CTE to determinen the item id and the insert iof the item_id doesn't exist

```
WITH CTE  as (
select item_vendor.item_id
from item_vendor
join item on item.id = item_vendor.item_id
WHERE "main"."item"."id" IN ('188646', '200000699'))
INSERT INTO "item_vendor" ("item_id", "vendor_id", audit_by, currency_id )
SELECT (item_id, 1, 1, 1)
FROM CTE c1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM item_vendor WHERE item_id = c1.item_id)
```

Comment: Can we make this generic so that we can any number of id's? We can have more than one ids that are missing which needs to be inserted but not just one.

Comment: i  changed it so that it will add all item_id that are not in item_vendor , but for the rest of the columns i don't know where they come from and so you need to join all tables that have that information  to `CTE c1`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to check if an id already exists. Put a unique index on `item_id` or make it the primary key. Postgres will automatically check if the value already exists. If you do nothing else the condition throws an exception, but you can alter this by extending the [insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-insert.html) to contain the `on conflict` clause. You can then either update the existing values or to just ignore (silently) the offending incoming row. So for this case:

```
insert into "main"."item_vendor" ("item_id", "vendor_id", audit_by, currency_id )
     values ('188646', ?, ?, ?),('200000699', ?, ?, ?)
  on conflict (item_id) 
  do nothing;
```